# Only show image from custom field when present

Tags: php, custom-field, images

How would I adjust the following code to only show the image tag when there is a variable present in the "imageembed" field?

```
<?php $imageid = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'imageembed', true); ?>
   <div class="newsimage"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $imageid ); ?>" width="640" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php    
  if (strlen($imageid = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'imageembed', true))) {
?>
    <div class="newsimage"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url((int) $imageid); ?>" width="640" /></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    $imageid = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'imageembed', true);
    if($imageid != '') 
       { ?>
        <div class="newsimage"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $imageid ); ?>" width="640" /></div>
<?php  } ?>
```

Use `if` condition to check if `$imageid` has any value in it or not.

Answer (score -1):

Simple. Use the **`if`** conditional statement, like this:

```
<?php
    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'imageembed', true) ) {
        $imageid = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'imageembed', true);
?>

    // Show when custom field has a value
    <div class="newsimage"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $imageid ); ?>" width="640" /></div>

<?php } ?>
```

**READ:** [Function Reference / get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) (WordPress Codex)